# Julia - How to resize image using function `imshow`?

Tags: image, julia

When I run the function `imshow` from ImageView.jl, the window containing the image is really small, and I have to maximize it every time.  Is there a simple attribute to fix this?
In other words, how to resize an image when using `imshow()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using version 0.10.13 or higher of ImageView, you can pass in a `canvassize`:

```
imshow([1 0; 0 1]; canvassize=(800, 800))
```